# Universal USB Installer can't detect usb

Tags: usb, wine

None of my usbs are detected in universal usb installer.I am running it in wine on ubuntu.My main HD and my dvd drive are detected but not my usbs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. run `winecfg`
2. go to the "Drives" tab
3. click "Add..."
4. chose your favorite letter
5. find the "Path:" text field and click the "Browse..." button next to that
6. find wherever your operating system has mounted the flash drive. In Ubuntu it'll be under /media
7. select your flash drive's mount point (if you're using YUMI it'll probably be called "MULTIBOOT".
8. click "OK" and then "OK" again.
9. Run YUMI or whetever Windows program you were using your flash drive with.

This was answered here [How to mount USB flash drive to WINE?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/314205/how-to-mount-usb-flash-drive-to-wine)

Comment: I think it is worthwhile mentioning that in order to get this to work on my system I needed to, within `winecfg`, go to the `Show Advanced` option for the flash drive and change `Type` from `Autodetect` to `Floppy Disk`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use Universal USB Installer in linux, there are plenty of linux tools to create bootable USB's.

I like the multi-boot usb method, described [here on Arch's Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Multiboot_USB_drive) or [here on pendrivelinux.com](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/boot-multiple-iso-from-usb-via-grub2-using-linux/), for many distros you just copy the ISO file onto the usb and edit grub.cfg. Cliff notes instructions are:

1. Mount the usb
2. Install grub by running the following command, replacing `x` with your actual USB device and `/mnt/usb` with the actual mounted dir.

   ```
   grub-install --force --no-floppy --boot-directory=/mnt/USB/boot /dev/sdx
   ```
3. Put demo grub.cfg ( http://pendrivelinux.com/downloads/multibootlinux/grub.cfg ) in /mnt/USB/boot/grub and edit to match your iso's

Or see the [Ubuntu help on creating & installing from bootable USB's](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick), can the Ubuntu tool Startup Disk Creator, Unetbootin, or plain `dd`.