# Trying to make a Windows 7 USB with UNetBootin, getting error "Failed to load COM32 file menu.c32"

Tags: boot, usb, windows, unetbootin

Pretty much what it says on the tin.

I looked around a bit, someone told me to press "Tab" to see a list of options, this is what it yielded.

```
Verifying DMI Pool Data ....................
Failed to load COM32 file menu.c32
boot:
 unetbootindefault
```

So, I selected that option, even though the OP of the fix said there would be several others.  This was the result,

```
boot: unetbootindefault
Loading /ubnkern. . . failed: No such file or directory
```

This was in the pre-boot screen, not in a terminal/command prompt anywhere.

Idk what to do at this point.  The installation went fine.  why am I getting this error?  How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I have recently answered similar [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/599864/how-to-create-windows-linux-bootable-usb-on-ubuntu-gui-style/599865#599865) using Unetbootin. Hope it help! Try, comment and vote